# Can't add style to my <asp:Label>?

Tags: asp.net, css

So i have this label in my master page and i would like change it's color and it's font :

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
```

my css code :

```
#Label1{
    font-size:36px;
    color:red;
}
```

and it doesn't work. Can someone explain why this doesn't work ?

Answer (score 2):

Set the ClientIDMode property to Static like this:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
```

Then it will retain the same ID on the client side.

An ASP.NET Label renders as a HTML `<span>` tag.

Alternatively just use the CssClass property of a ASP.NET control to set it's CSS class like so:

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label1" CssClass="label"></asp:Label>
```

Comment: well, it works if i use css class. But can't i use id ? Like for html tags ?

Comment: No when you set the `runat="server"` property it means that you are asking ASP.NET to process the control as opposed to the client-side. If you want the ASP.NET control to keep the same ID you set for it, you use the `ClientIDMode="Static"` property so that when it renders in the browser, the ID will still be "Label1"

Comment: ok. i understand. it works with ClientIdMode="static" too. Thank you.